# select rows between two dates in sqlite using java

Tags: sqlite, javafx

select rows between two dates in sqlite using java.
When i try to retrieve rows between to two dates from sqlite database in javafx program i always get one row from the whole rows even if there is multiple rows it select the first row and discard the remaining or not included in the result set at all, how can solve this problem and again the database has some records but the query always return the first one

```
@FXML
private void report(ActionEvent event)
{
    if(searchfromDate.getValue() != null && searchToDate.getValue() != null)
    {
        try
        {
            DBconnector.connect();

            LocalDate startDate = searchfromDate.getValue();
            LocalDate endDate = searchToDate.getValue();

            String query = "select * from selled where date between '" + startDate
                           + "' and '" + endDate + "'";
            ResultSet rs = DBconnector.query(query);
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);

            JSONObject file = new JSONObject();

            if(rs.next())
            {
                int id = rs.getInt("id");
                String customer = rs.getString("costomer");
                String name = rs.getString("name");
                String barcode = rs.getString("barcode");
                int amount = rs.getInt("amount");
                LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(rs.getString("date"));
                double price = rs.getDouble("price");
                String garentee = rs.getString("garentee");

                file.put("id", id);
                file.put("customer", customer);
                file.put("name", name);
                file.put("barcode", barcode);
                file.put("amount", amount);
                file.put("date", date);
                file.put("price", price);
                file.put("garentee", garentee);
            }

            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("تقرير المبيعات.json");

            writer.write(file.toString());
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();

            alert.setTitle("رسالة تاكيد");
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.setContentText("تم استخراج الملف بنجاح");
            alert.showAndWait();

            Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
            desktop.browse(new URI("https://arabsefr.com/save-report?fbclid=IwAR2ON1Tl8ETQ--3QEAVFJLMjTuWUhpLCZrD3PXhg8TZpdlUH4umKBfl78OM"));
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }

    else
    {
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);

        alert.setTitle("رسالة تاكيد");
        alert.setHeaderText(null);
        alert.setContentText("لم يتم تحديد التاريخ");
        alert.showAndWait();
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you try using a [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)?

Comment: If you want more than one row, I suspect `if` is not what you want to use.

Comment: yes, i use this

Comment: and it always return the first record and ignore the other?

Comment: Ah, @Shawn is correct. You're using `if (rs.next()) { ... }` but you want to use `while (rs.next()) { ... }`. Remember that a `ResultSet` has a cursor and each time you call `next()`, and that method returns `true`, it advances the cursor to the next row. Since an `if` will only check the condition once, you only process one row of the result set.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using SQLite, use of strftime() method is always recommended while manipulating with dates this makes sure that future troubles are avoided.

WHERE strftime('%s', date) between strftime('%s', startDate) and strftime('%s', endDate)